# What is the difference between missing blocks and missing blocks (with replication factor 1)?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When I issue the `hdfs dfsadmin -report` command, I see 2 confusing entries and I don't understand their difference:

- Missing blocks
- Missing blocks (with replication factor 1)

Tom White, in his book uses the term corrupt and missing blocks interchangeably. So, missing blocks means blocks whose replicas are all corrupt.

Then what does `Missing blocks (with replication factor 1)` mean? What is the difference? I tried googling and found only very confusing explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `dfsadmin report` shows two types of missing blocks:

1. Missing blocks -
2. Missing blocks (with replication factor 1) -

First **Missing block** - shows the number of blocks which have valid replicas and can be recovered. Example : If there are missing blocks 1342, those will have more be replicated eventually.

Second **Missing block(with Replication factor 1)** - shows the number of blocks whose replicas are corrupted and unrecoverable. Since the minimum replication factor is 1, hence it shows as `with replication factor 1`.